# Get base url in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, base-url

I've created a custom footer template inside my theme folder `app/design/Vendor/Module/Magento_Email/email/footer.html` , the problem is i need to get base url inside this html file.

Comment: Can  you please upload your file code here?

Comment: You can use __`{{store url=""}}`__ in email templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **You can setup the url using js file.**

First of all add mage/url to the list of dependencies.
Then add the below function to your js file.

```
getBaseUrl: function() {
    return url.build('<your_url_path>');
},
```

**Then use the knockout to set href**

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }">Add Some Text</a>
```

**Then must clear the varnish and browser cache and check**

Comment: @IdhamChoudry please upvote answer if  it's useful for you. So, other can use this answer.

Comment: Huh, this question is about email templates, not knockout html templates and ui component view models... Or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: How is this the selected answer? This has nothing to do with email templates

Answer (score 1):

you can use `{{store url=""}}` in email template

Comment: For a multistore website, this gives what the name says: a _store_ URL, not the _base_ URL. Like https://www.example.com/en/